# ArrayList to int[] in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have my declaration as follows

```
int[] EmpIDs = new int[] { };
ArrayList arrEmpID = new ArrayList();
int EmpID = 0;
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
{
   EmpID = 123;
   arrEmpID.Add(EmpID);
}
if (CheckBox2.Checked)
{
   EmpID = 1234;
   arrEmpID.Add(EmpID);
}
if (CheckBox3.Checked)
{
   EmpID = 1234;
   arrEmpID.Add(EmpID);
}
```

After all i would like to assign this the `EmpIDs` which was declared as `int array`

I tried this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrEmpID.Count; i++)
    {
        EmpIDs = arrEmpID.ToArray(new int[i]);
    }
```

But i am unable to add can any one help me

Comment: If you are in .net-2.0, use the [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should avoid using `ArrayList`. Instead use `List<int>`, which has a method `ToArray()`

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(123);
list.Add(456);
int[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

When converting an ArrayList to an array, you'll have to specify the type of the objects that it contains, and, you'll have to make sure you cast the result to an array of the desired type as well:

```
int[] empIds;

empIds = (int[])arrEmpID.ToArray(typeof(int));
```

But, as pointed out by others, why are you using an `ArrayList` ?  If you're using .NET 1.1, you indeed have no other choice then using an `ArrayList`.
However, if you're using .NET 2.0 or above, you should use a `List<int>` instead.

Comment: Very useful answer - in the .Net Micro Framework there are no generics and so one has to use `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the (old) `ArrayList` class, use a (mordern) `List<int>`. It's type safe and it has a [ToArray method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
List<int> arrEmpID = new List<int>(); 
if (CheckBox1.Checked) 
    arrEmpID.Add(1234); 
if (CheckBox2.Checked) 
    arrEmpID.Add(1234); 
if (CheckBox3.Checked) 
    arrEmpID.Add(1234); 

int[] EmpIDs = arrEmpID.ToArray();
```

In fact, you might consider using the `List<int>` all along instead of creating an `int[]` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need `ArrayList`, you can try using the following:

```
EmpIDs = arrEmpID.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

(But this is only available in .NET 3.5 and above)

Comment: OfType is a LINQ extension method. I don't think it's available in .net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
EmpIDs= new int[arrEmpID.Count]; // initilise the array 
for (int i = 0; i < arrEmpID.Count; i++)
    {
        EmpIDs[i] = arrEmpID[i]; // set each value
    }
```

the fault with your code is that you are not initilizing the array to the size of the arrayList.

Comment: That's not true.  You do not have to initialize the array if you're assigning another array to it.  You just have to declare it.

Comment: @Frederik Gheysels, I was referring to this piece of code.. 
`int[] EmpIDs = new int[] { };` the technique you suggested doesn't require for the array to be initialized but mine did..

Comment: This is particularly odd piece of code though - why would you want to *repeatedly* overwrite the same variable? It seems very unlikely that this does what the OP wants.

Comment: oops.. had copied code from the question.. have modified it now though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
EmpIDs = arrEmpID.ToArray(typeof(int));
```